# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Thank in advance for your response.

I am trying to filter an angular material table, but I'm having one issue as I'm trying to filter with an input and cehckboxes. The filtering with checkboxes works perfectly, but, when trying to filter with the input valie is giving me this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.
It shows only when introducing something in the input to filter the table. The filtering with checkboxes is not showing any errors.

I have tried to make npm cache clean --force f, then npm install, but I don't think it's an angular issue, I'm using 12.18.3 node version. I also tried to initialize the value of the JSON with no success.

The complete error is :

```
core.js:6014 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at MatTableDataSource.dataSource.filterPredicate (provisioned-list.component.ts:116)
    at table.js:568
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at MatTableDataSource._filterData (table.js:568)
    at MapSubscriber.project (table.js:543)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:29)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber.notifyNext (combineLatest.js:73)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
```

¿how can I fix this?

my html:

```
 <div fxLayout="row">
              <mat-form-field class="filterField">
                <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter"
                  [(ngModel)]='filterValue'>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <div fxLayout="row">
              <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="onlineValue"
                (change)="applyFilterOn('isOnline',onlineValue ? true : false)">
                Online</mat-checkbox>

              <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="offlineValue"
                (change)="applyFilterOn('isOnline',offlineValue ? false : true)">
                Offline</mat-checkbox>

                <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="provisionedValue"
                (change)="applyFilterOn('isProvisioned',provisionedValue ? true : false)">
                Provisioned</mat-checkbox>

                <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="deprovisionedValue"
                (change)="applyFilterOn('isProvisioned',deprovisionedValue ? false : true)">
                Deprovisioned</mat-checkbox>
            </div>
```

The problem seems to be in the JSON parse (line 116-->    const filterValues = JSON.parse(filter);)

my ts:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataSource.filterPredicate = ((data: DeviceModel, filter: string): boolean => {
            const filterValues = JSON.parse(filter);
            console.log(filterValues)

            return (this.onlineValue ? data.isOnline === filterValues.isOnline : true) &&
                (this.offlineValue ? data.isOnline === filterValues.isOnline : true) && 
                (this.provisionedValue ? data.isProvisioned === filterValues.isProvisioned : true) &&
                (this.deprovisionedValue ? data.isProvisioned === filterValues.isProvisioned : true);
        });





 applyFilterOn(column: string, filterValueOn: string): void {   
         this.filterValues[column] = filterValueOn;
        this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues);
       
    }

applyFilter(filterValue: string): void {
        filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
        filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
    }
```

Comment: You missed to add the error to the question , could you please add the full error ? Also if possible what json you are dealing with and what is the input you are trying when it gives this error , or is it with all the inputs?

Comment: Seems `filter` is not a string; it's an object. hence getting the error

Comment: Try to `console.log(filter)` before parsing. 
Something is wrong with `filter`s value

Comment: this.dataSource.filterPredicate = ((data: DeviceModel, filter: string): boolean => {
            console.log(filter, typeof(filter)) //{"isOnline":true,"isProvisioned":false} string

Comment: @novita , no need to parse the data you can directly use , ```this.onlineValue ? data.isOnline === filter.isOnline : true``` . You are getting string in console.log(typeof(string)) because you said the type of filter to be string in the method declaration.